# What is the significance of mirror projection scenes in Trance?

Tags: analysis, trance

*[Trance](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1924429/)* contains some scenes which consist of mirror projections:

[image]
[image]

My Question is: **What is the significance of these mirror scenes as this in itself is a psychological thriller**?